# How to split string in every 6th strings which are the subsets of a dataframe column?

Tags: python

In a dataframe column, I would like to split subset data in format of strings into every 6 digits and add a comma ',' so that I can get a list of hs codes under the column. I tried the below but it needs some correction.

```
df.loc[df[:, 1] for i in range(0, len(['id'], 6)
```

Comment: So what did you already write to do that? (e.g. lots of answers on SO on how to split a string every X characters, did none of that help?)

Comment: Every 6 from the start or from the end?  Meaning, if the id value is `12345678`, do you want `12,345678` or `123456,78`?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, not an image, and the matching expected output

Comment: For example, I would like to split the id string in the first raw into 280530, 284442, 284690

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Column 1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        'id': [2468938493843983, 345642232, 23343433]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['id'] = df['id'].astype(str)
df['fromleft'] = [','.join([df['id'][i][j:j+6] for j in range(0, len(df['id'][i]), 6)]) for i in range(len(df))]

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Column 1                id            fromleft
0        a  2468938493843983  246893,849384,3983
1        b         345642232          345642,232
2        c          23343433           233434,33
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to split from the left:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].astype(str).str.replace(r'(.{6})(?=.)', r'\1,', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
                     id
0  280530,284442,284690
```